# Prohibiting external files in git

Tags: git

We have a commonly occurring problem. We are using the repo tool to put multiple git repos into a build tree. Unfortunately users keep adding (probably with a -f) and commiting files that are in other repos. Example:

```
#ls
root/gitRepoA
root/gitRepoB
#cd root/gitRepoA
#git add -f ../gitRepoB/myFile
#git commit
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

EDIT: This seems to be only possible when using the repo tool.

Comment: Do you have the exact 'repo' command used to add file from another repo?

Comment: repo is just used to download the code (everything under the root folder). At that point the sequence in the example recreates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be possible, if both directories are git repos (ie have a `.git`)

I just tried:

```
C:\prog\git\tests\multipleRepos\r2a>git add -f ..\r1\f1r1
fatal: '..\r1\f1r1' is outside repository
```

Comment: You are right. It looks like this is only happening when using the repo tool. I will update the question.